# How to import SQL dump into Postgres DB running on Vagrant instance of Ubuntu

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using Postgres via a vagrant instance running ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg box and I have an sql dump from another developer.

By the way, I tried using PGAdmin IV from my Win 10 host machine after I had connected to the Postgres server on the virtualbox (ubuntu) but it takes forever and not running.

How can I import this to the Postgres running on virtualbox instance?

Comment: There's not really much difference to import locally or on VM. just ssh into the VM (`vagrant ssh`)  and run import command (`psql databasename < data_base_dump`)

Comment: The thing is the database dump reside in the host machine but the pg database runs from the headless virtual machine

Comment: so use a [vagrant synced folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) in this case to share the dump between the host and the guest

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So given an sql dump file as `dump.sql`.

1. Run `vagrant ssh` on an ssh client like git bash(for windows)
2. Put the dump file in the directory containing the vagrantfile on the host machine. As it [syncs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) by default with the guest machine or run `vagrant rsync`, just to make sure.
3. Navigate to the vagrant directory on the host machine (eg `cd ../../` for an ubuntu guest on a window host)
4. Run `psql -h hostname -U test -d databasename -f dump.sql`.

Comment: alternatively, run the command directly with `vagrant ssh` and the `-c` flag, for example:

`vagrant ssh -c "sudo su - postgres -c 'psql -d databasename -a -f dump.sql'"`

And in that command using `sudo su - postgres -c` to run the command as the postgres user, when you don't want to adapt the user roles and want to run certain commands like COPY.. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of the dump (normal or custom), you can use `psql` or `pg_restore`.
Check the `--format` option in the documentation for [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following the simple steps below solves my problem:

1. After `vagrant up`, `vagrant ssh` to log into the os
2. Type `psql` command
3. Then `create database your_db_name` to create the empty db
4. Make sure the dump sql file is in the folder containing the **vagrantfile** ( cd vagrant) or a sub folder within
5. Write this command to import the dump file into the newly create db
   `your_db_name -f /path/to/the/dump.sql`

I hope the steps will help you too.